# Is it possible to load fixtures after setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

In my Rails application I'm using PostgreSQL schemas and not every schema contains all tables. (Especially the default path does not) This leads to some problems with fixture loading in `Test::Unit`.

I'm setting the schema search path in `setup`, but if I enable fixtures using `fixtures` they get loaded *before* my setup modifies the search path and the fixtures cannot be loaded.

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  fixtures :model1, :model2     #Fixtures are loaded before setup below

  setup do
    # Setup schema search path
  end
end
```

Is it possible to delay loading of the fixtures until after `setup` or to modify the database connection before the fixtures get loaded? (Note: Not all tests work on the *same* search path!)

Some background: The existing tests are from an older version without different schemas, so I don't want to rewrite all test just yet using some other means of test data generation, although for future tests I'll definitly switch to factory_girl.

Comment: Currently, what the `fixtures`line does is to prepare the named fixtures so that they can be accessed by `models(:name1)` etc. Even if that line is excluded, the records would exist in the test database by the time setup is executed.